# When i try to validate on list inside object data annotation not work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, data-annotations

iam trying to validate object in my api this object contain list of another object i need to validate that the list count must be more than 0 and the property inside list have another data annotation need to validate also

``

```
  public class CmsRequestBody
   {

    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public int n { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locale")]
    [Required]
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("questionList")]
    [Required]
    [EnsureOneElement(ErrorMessage = "At least a person is required")]
    [ValidateEachItemAttribute]

    public List<Question> QuestionList;
}

public class Question
{
    [Required]
    [TwelveDigit]
    [JsonProperty("objectId")]
    public long ObjectId { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value bigger than {1}")]
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("instanceNumber")]
    public int InstanceNumber { get; set; }
}``
```

this is the  object and my custom data annotation attribute when i add break point in data annotation custom code  not  Enter the code

Answer (score 0):

the answer that iam missing to add

`{ get; set; }` for property

```
public List<Question> QuestionList
```